# I can't find how many times the values in the color column match the same id in the id column.?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't find how many times the values in the color column match the same id in the id column

.     [image]

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```